# WooCommerce Stars rating in product by category view (Gutenberg block)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I try to hook the "star rating" to "products by category view" (Gutenberg block).

[image]

At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

For the normal shop/category pages I use following code in the function.php of my WordPress theme to add the "star rating" to the products:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_star_rating' );

function add_star_rating()
{
    global $woocommerce, $product;
    $average = $product->get_average_rating();
    $rating_count = $product->get_rating_count();
    $review_count = $product->get_review_count();

    echo '<div class="star-rating"><span style="width:'.( ( $average / 5 ) * 100 ) . '%"><strong itemprop="ratingValue" class="rating">'.$average.'</strong> '.__( 'out of 5', 'woocommerce' ).'</span></div>';
    echo '<div class="divRefCount"><span class="revCount">('.$review_count.')</span></div>';
}
```

How can I add this to the Gutenberg block for every single item/product in a category? 
It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use the the category shortcut.

```
[products columns="4" category="44" orderby="menu_order"]
```

But this don't change the Gutenberg problematic.